# datatables button and search box position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

hi i am using datatables and using bootstrap styling. can anybody please tell me how to achieve this kind of layout for my buttons and search box? (i am using adobe photoshop to generate this view)

[image: view]

i have tried to change dom in javascript

```
var table = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
    dom: '<"col-sm-12"B><"col-sm-12"f>t',
    select: true,
    scrollY: '80vh',
    scrollX: true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    scrollCollapse : true,
    paging : false,
    stateSave : true,
    order : [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    buttons: [],
    language: {
        buttons : {},
        select:{
            rows:{
                _: "",
                0: "",
                1: ""
            }
        },
        "emptyTable": "Tidak terdapat data di tabel",
        "info": "",
        "infoEmpty": "",
        "infoFiltered":   "",
        "search": "<i class='fa fa-search'></i>",
        "paginate": {
            "next":       ">",
            "previous":   "<"
        },
        "zeroRecords": "Tidak ditemukan data yang sesuai",
    }
});
```

but get is like this... i having hard time to change search box html structure

[image: view2]

i just can't tap into html structure that created by datatables.. and having hard time to trying to understand the whole datatables jquery files...

if only i can control html structure then i believe the html code will be like this...

```
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="btn-group">
            //the button in here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search term...." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        //table in here
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by reading [this](https://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/), which explains the fairly strict limitations on styling for inputs with `type=search` applied to them.  The search box in DataTables is such an input.

This comes from the linked article.  Add this CSS to your style sheet:

```
input[type=search] {
   -moz-appearance:none;
   -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

That should cancel out the styling that the user agent coerces on search boxes.  If it doesn't, you might consider programmatically changing the `type` of the box from `search` to `text`:

```
$('.datatables_filter input').attr('type', 'text');
```

If you resort to that, you'll want to put the statement in a function in the `initComplete` option when you call the `DataTable` method, if you can get away with it (the doc doesn't clarify whether all the markup is drawn if "your table has fully been initialised") If not, you'll have to use the `drawCallback` option .